# How to catch the exception unsupported major .minor version exception in java

Tags: java, exception

By chaining java version to higher problem will be solved but i don't want to do in that way . I want to catch the exception and throw user understandable message . it will possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could wrap a try / catch around the code that throws an "unsupported version" exception, then catching `Throwable` would do it.  (It would be better to catch the more specific exception `UnsupportedClassVersionError` though ...)

However there are some important caveats:

- The exception is often thrown when you are starting the JVM, and exceptions thrown during JVM startup cannot be caught.  (They typically happen *before* any of your application's code is run; i.e. before your `main` method, before any static initialization.)

  Or to put it another way, you typically CANNOT put the try / catch around the code that throws this exception.
- The other circumstance is when you attempt to dynamically load a class (e.g. `Class.forName`) ... not when launching an application. In your original (now deleted) code, the `launch` method might be loading a class, and calling a static or instance method to "launch" the application.
- Catching the exception for any purpose other than diagnosis is a *bad idea*.  The exception an `Error` exception, and these  exceptions are generally speaking NOT recoverable.

Comment: Is it right? what he is asking is, launch(args) will throw major minor version exception. Practically if it is like that, then the main method itself will not trigger right?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram - It is possible that his `launch` method is using `Class.forName()` or similar to load a class, and *that is throwing the exception*.  Anyhow, my first bullet already explains that the exception won't be catchable if it happens during JVM launch.

Comment: Plus1 You are right.. In the question it was not mentioned properly. I confused..